Is it possible to remove caffeine from brewed coffee?
I'm testing how the coffee brewing method influences its caffeine content. I had originally thought about using ethyl acetate, methylene chloride, or Swiss water processing to remove the caffeine, but none of those methods would allow me to test already brewed coffee. Any suggestions?
I'm a high school student just getting into doing personal labs, so sorry if this is an obvious question.
Thank you!

These methods would work

Extraction from brewed coffee should be easier than from grains, otherwise not much difference.

The question is, if you still want to drink it.

Commercially, CO2 is often used. Safe chemically, but the pressure required might be an obstacle. Hint: don't use glass apparatus ;-)

just fyi, there are almost 200 Stack Exchange sites and one of them is Coffee!
